# Can't convert String to int while saving into excel sheet

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

> main.py:697: FutureWarning: Use of **kwargs is deprecated, use engine_kwargs instead.
> Excelwriter = pd.ExcelWriter(Excel_File_Name,engine="xlsxwriter",options={'strings_to_numbers': True})

I'm getting this warning while saving the excel sheet.
I've tried the following to convert the string values to int:-

`Excelwriter = pd.ExcelWriter(Excel_File_Name,engine="xlsxwriter",options={'strings_to_numbers': True})`

I found this (**options={'strings_to_numbers': True}**) solution to convert string to int while saving the excel sheet and tried other methods as well but none seems to be working.

**Edit1:-**

My Final code looks like this, but the strings aren't converted to Int yet:-

```
    dflist= [Income_Statement_Annual]
    Excel_File_Name = Company_name + ".xlsx"
    Excelwriter = pd.ExcelWriter(Excel_File_Name,engine="xlsxwriter",engine_kwargs={'options': {'strings_to_numbers': True}})

    for df in dflist:
        df.to_excel(Excelwriter, sheet_name=retrieve_name(df)[0],index=False)
    Excelwriter.save()
```

Screenshot of My sheet: -
[image: Output_Sheet]
Anything still wrong?

Comment: You will need to remove the commas from the strings before they can be converted to numbers.

Comment: OMG completely forgot about that xD, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html) and the error message are pretty clear about how you should make the method call.

```
Excelwriter = pd.ExcelWriter(
    Excel_File_Name, 
    engine="xlsxwriter", 
    engine_kwargs={"options": {"strings_to_numbers": True}}
)
```

Any *options* specific to the `engine` have to be passed in as a `dict` to the `engine_kwargs` keyword argument.

Comment: Understood, I'll try this. Thanks!

Comment: The syntax isn't very obvious but it should actually be: `engine_kwargs={'options': {'strings_to_numbers': True}}`.

Comment: changed it to that, I thought it was one or the other but wasn't sure

Comment: I've added one edit to my question, could you check?

Comment: that would be an implementation detail of the `xlsx` writer that you're using, you'll need to check what the _exact_ arguments you need to pass are, however the issue of the `FutureWarning` have been solved